User agent becomes grpc-go/1.64. on server side of grpc gateway
I'm trying to create an app using grpc-gateway and go but faced with the problem. I'm trying to write an interceptor that will authorize users before the requests using cookie and user agent. However the user-agent that I try to get is grpc-go/1.64, which is wrong as I send requests through postman.
I have a method that setups my grpc grpc server
func customHeaderMatcher(key string) (string, bool) {
    switch key {
    case "Cookie":
        logger.Info(key)
        return key, true
    case "User-Agent":
        logger.Info(key)
        return key, true
    default:
        return runtime.DefaultHeaderMatcher(key)
    }
}

func (s *Server) MapHandlers() {

    logger.Info("Trying to map handlers...")

    s.mux = runtime.NewServeMux(
        runtime.WithIncomingHeaderMatcher(customHeaderMatcher),
    )

    s.grpcServer = grpc.NewServer(
        grpc.ChainUnaryInterceptor(
            grpcConnector.LoggerInterceptor(),
            func(ctx context.Context, req any, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (resp any, err error) {
                md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
                if !ok {
                   return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unauthenticated, "MDWManager.AuthedMiddleware: missing metadata")
                }

               userAgent := md.Get("User-Agent")
               if len(userAgent) == 0 {
                   return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unauthenticated, "MDWManager.AuthedMiddleware: cannot get User-agent")
               }
    
               logger.Infof("UserAgent=%s", userAgent)
            },
        ),
    )
   ...
}

I started digging into the go-grpc library sources and noticed that wrong context gets on server side of grpc connection because function that receives requests in grpc handleStream() has context with user agent

I decided to check what context I send to the server in grpc function newClientStreamWithParams() which is stored in client part of grpc library. And there's the context is right because the clientStream struct contains the context with right user-agent

So what can be wrong? Thank you in advance!
